# How do physics engines like Box2D detect and respond to collisions between arbitrary polygons?

Tags: collision-detection, box2d, collision-resolution

[image: Two intersecting polygons.]

I've always wondered how collision detection like this was achieved, and I've always wondered what the response would be. Do they perform line-line intersection tests for each line making up the two polygons? If it'd make the question any more specific, how does Box2D handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2D collisions with non-rectangular shapes are often detected using the Separating Axis Theorem (tutorial [here](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)). Look it up, there are a lot of good articles on the subject.

Box2D uses it as part of the solution for their collision system, for a more in-depth view read their [manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf).